# RegEx to find unique occurences of a match

Tags: regex

I have found a couple of related threads:
[Regular expression - match all words but match unique words only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061349/regular-expression-match-all-words-but-match-unique-words-only-once) and 
[get unique regex matcher results (without using maps or lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613813/get-unique-regex-matcher-results-without-using-maps-or-lists)
there are a few others but I just could not get their solutions to solve my issues.

I've been reading on looharounds and backreferences but I'm still missing something.

I need to search through several large code-bases, and find all unique occurrences of data source names or variables for them.

I tried the following regular expressions:

```js
(datasource=\"(.*?)\")(?!.+\1)
(datasource=\"(.*?)\")(?!.*\1)
(datasource=\"(.*?)\")(?!.+\2)
(datasource=\"(.*?)\")(?!.*\2)
(datasource=\"(.*?)(?!.+\1)\")
(datasource=\"(.*?)(?!.*\1)\")
(datasource=\"(.*?)(?!.+\2)\")
(datasource=\"(.*?)(?!.*\2)\")
```

```html
datasource="someDSN"
datasource="anotherDNS"
datasource = "anotherDNS"
datasource="someDSN"
```

The code can be complex, but basically it looks something like this:\

```html
  <cfquery name="qry_getEvent" datasource="#APPLICATION.firstDSN#">
    SELECT * 
    FROM events
    WHERE id = 1
  </cfquery>
  
    <cfquery name="qry_getPlayers" datasource="#APPLICATION.firstDSN#">
    SELECT * 
    FROM players
    WHERE event_id = 1
  </cfquery>
  
    <cfquery name="qry_getLocation" datasource="secondDSN">
    SELECT * 
    FROM locations
    WHERE event_id = 1
  </cfquery>
```

The result should look something like:

```
#APPLICATION.firstDSN#
secondDSN
```

The only semi-solution I've discovered is to run the (datasource=\"([^"]*)\") multiple times, but after every time, prefix it with a known value to exclude it for example:

```html
(?!datasource="dsnname1"|datasource="dsnname2")(datasource=\"([^"]*)\")
```

This helped me narrow down all the DSN names in a few minutes, but would have been so much easier if I could just get all the distinct results automatically.  Maybe this need a little Node.js work added to it to streamline the process

Comment: It must be unique because you're afraid you'll match the pattern multiple times per line?  Would not just be simpler to match and use the first datasource found that meets the `datasource="something"` criteria?

Comment: is there any reason you can't just put the matches in a set?

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/ozFNPV/1). Do not use it. Using a single regex to search huge amounts of text data like this is not the best idea. Better match all the strings and then det distinct data using programmatic means.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it should be `(datasource\s*=\s*\"([^"]*)\")(?!.+\2)` since you want to ensure the contents are not duplicated, not the whole `datasource` attribute. The OP also presented a couple strings with spaces before/after the `=`, so I've added that to the expression

Comment: @Neil, I just wanted a quick way to see all the different data sources that are being referenced.  I guess I could write this in Node and have it run against Git repos, but that'd be a lot more work than just putting a regex in VS Code or Dreamweaver and doing a search.

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for that solution. I understand why it should not be used.  But it seems to work fine in that link but when I try it in Espresso or Dreamweaver I still get all the results coming back.  Odd.

Comment: Yes, you do not use `(?s)`