# Java Regex FileName not repeated

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to set a validation for not repeated file names, if some file is repeated it should be writen this way:

- FILENAME.PDF
- FILENAME_1.PDF
- FILENAME_2.PDF

So I can make the first one, but all the rest how can be taken?.

I will get a list of all filenames documents before, so now im trying to make like a for each document but i dont know how to make regex for get it.

FILENAME_1.PDF -> REGEX() -> GET RETURN -> 1

---

**UPDATE**

If I have this files in my bbdd: [filename.pdf, filename_1.pdf, filename_2.pdf].

I need when someone upload some new, based on that files, my new name will be filename_3.pdf if exist file name 2.

**FILENAME_VERSION.EXTENSION**

Base on this i need get the version of the last filename. Thanks!

Note: There will be more filesnames differents, for example FILANEM_FILENAM_VERSION.pdf

---

Thanks you!

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regex? Just use a hashmap with filename occurancies - <name, count>. Don't overcomplicated the simple task.

Comment: Could you add the expected output for your example ? "So I can make the first one, but all the rest how can be taken ?" This sentence is unclear. You want to get all copy of the first, or only the first and ignore copy ?

Comment: I cant use hashmap, only filename. @Amongalen

Comment: I want to get the last version of copys, for create the new one, with the version increased. I will update my asnwer.
@vincrichaud

Comment: Why you `can't` use hashmap? Is it some kind of a homework or something? Maybe have a look at this - regex that fidns unique results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613813/get-unique-regex-matcher-results-without-using-maps-or-lists

Comment: `_(\d+)\.[^.]+$` would extract the number (it captures the number that precedes the last dot in the filename and follows an underscore, you can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/2A71wP/2)). I'm really not sure how that helps solving your problem though.

Comment: How do you know that filename doesn't contain numbers in it? Can't a file be named `filename_1.pdf`? Its copy would be `filename_1_1.pdf`

Comment: thats why i need the regex, every file with NAME_version.PDF will be the same with version increased, so it should be filename_2.pdf and not filename_1_1.pdf @Amongalen

Comment: not getting the version of filename, sry @Aaron is java regex?

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña I've added an answer with an ideone link with java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex :

```
_(\d+)\.[^.]+$
```

Or in Java :

```
_(\\d+)\\.[^.]+$
```

The regex captures a number between an underscore and the last dot of the filename.

The number you seek is captured in the first capturing group and needs to be extracted using `Matcher.group`.

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/Det2yX) :

> No version found in filename.pdf
>   No version found in filename1.pdf
>   filename_1.pdf - version found : 1
>   filename1_2.pdf - version found : 2
>   No version found in filename_1.test.pdf
>   filename_1.test_2.pdf - version found : 2
>   No version found in filename_1